# Using webgl-texture-utils with three.js for dds/crn support

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use webgl-texture-utils ( https://github.com/toji/webgl-texture-utils ) with Three.js (r56) to take advantage of DDS and CRN (http://code.google.com/p/crunch/) textures.

I cannot figure out how to use the texture returned by `textureLoader.load(src, callback);` in `THREE.Texture(image, mapping);`

THREE.Texture expects javascript Image() object, but texture-utils returns something reported by Firebug to be `XrayWrapper [Object WebGLTexture {}` which I assume to be some native WebGL texture type.

Can I use that texture somehow as the image for THREE.Texture?

Here's some code I tried:

```
var mapping = new THREE.UVMapping();

var image = new Image();
var map = null;

var usetexturetools = true;

if (!usetexturetools) { 

  // normal way of loading

  map = new THREE.Texture( image, mapping );
  var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
  loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
    map.image = event.content;
    map.needsUpdate = true;
  });
  loader.addEventListener( 'error', function ( event ) {
    window.console.log("error loading " + texture);
  });
  loader.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  loader.load(texture, image);

} else {

 // using webgl-texture-tools - not working because i don't know how to use the object returned by textureLoader.load() with THREE.Texture..

 var textureLoader = new TextureUtil.TextureLoader(renderer.getContext());

 map = new THREE.Texture(textureLoader.load(texture, function(loaded) {
    window.console.log(loaded);
    map.needsUpdate = true;
 }), mapping );

}

map.sourceFile = texture;
map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

map.offset.x = this.getParameter("texture_offset_x");
map.offset.y = this.getParameter("texture_offset_y");

map.repeat.x = this.getParameter("texture_scale_x");
map.repeat.y = this.getParameter("texture_scale_y");
```

EDIT: I guess I could create a fork of webgl-texture-utils that instead of creating and returning WebGLTexture, would only return the raw data and as such, would allow me to use that data in THREE.DataTexture(). I'll try that when I get to it... Looking at the source looks like it might be quite a lot of work, but unless anything comes up, I'll try that.

Comment: `THREE.ImageUtils.loadCompressedTexture()` may be easier -- if it suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that too, but it doesn't support CRN, and I might be wrong but I believe texturetools will convert DDS to some usable format where it's not natively supported by the browser/driver. CRN would be nice to minimize both internet bandwidth and GPU memory usage.

Comment: how is this going @yaku? I'm interested.

Comment: @frank i'm busy with other work at the moment, planning to continue with this in a week or so

Comment: ...but I'm now pretty sure the solution involves rewriting parts of textureutils as described in my last edit

Comment: CRN isnt supported as is by graphic cards and probably won't be. The formats intend is to be compress it as best as possible, to have best transfer rates over the wire. Than you should convert CRN to DDS. DDS than can be used in the graphic card, if the browser + GC supports it. So your goal should be using new `THREE.CompressedTexture()` and set the converted CRN as mipmaps to the compressed texture. Trying to work it out, maybe i can push an answer.